# Regex to wrap text with tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JavaScript regex to wrap "#hashtags" with `<span>` tags

Example:

Before: "I need #help, please. #Thanks"

After: "I need `<span>`#help`</span>`, please. `<span>`#Thanks`</span>`"

Currently, `/#\w*\b/g` finds all of the #hashtags but how do I wrap them in span tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works -

```
str = "I need #help, please. #Thanks"
str = str.replace(/(\#[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/g,"<span>$1</span>");
//> "I need <span>#help</span>, please. <span>#Thanks</span>"
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: I guess you already know that, but it's worth noting that `\w` matches any alphanumerical character (word characters) including underscore (short for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), so, you could replace `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]` with `[-\w]`.

Comment: is this solution case sensitive?... meaning would it ignore the case sensitivity when the "str" has variations?

Comment: @Amjo No if you want it to ignore case you put the 'i' flag at the end after the slash. In this example he has the 'g' flag at the end.