# jQuery wrap text in span after special character

Tags: jquery

I want to wrap everything in my H1 tag that comes after the character `-`

I tried the following but it's simply removing everything after that character.

```
// Document ready
$('h1').text().replace(/-.*$/, '<span class="searchTerm">$&</span>');
```

CURRENT HTML

```
 <h1>Search - Apple</h1>
```

DESIRED HTML

```
 <h1>Search - <span class="searchTerm">Apple</span></h1>
```

Comment: Do either of these answer your question? [Find a string of text in an element and wrap some span tags round it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it) Or [Regex to wrap text with tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651239/regex-to-wrap-text-with-tags)

Comment: `"abc-def".replace(/-.*$/, '<span class="searchTerm">$&</span>')` seems to work ok - is your class `searchTerm` set to `display:none`?

Comment: its do not have any display none property, the script simply makes the H1 tag blank

Comment: In your code, what is `this` (or what do you think it is)?  What's the context that your code is running under?  doc.ready? global (not in a function)?  a different button click handler?  Tip: it's not the `h1` unless there is other context such as click event on the `h1`

Comment: You should edit your question, click the `[<>]` snippet button and provide a working snippet that *demonstrates* the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: Change `$('h1').html($(this).text()...` to `$('h1').html($('h1').text()...`

Comment: Your latest edit `$('h1').text().replace` won't make any changes, you still need the `$("h1").html(` part to make the changes.

Comment: $('h1').html($('h1').text().replace(/-.*$/, '<span class="searchTerm">$&</span>')); this is resulting into making the - character part of that span.

Comment: Change to `.replace/-(.*)$/` and `$1`

Comment: result i am getting is `code`<h1>SEARCH <span class="searchTerm">- Apple</span></h1>`code`  the - should be outside the span tag

Comment: it worked, can u post it as an answer please so i can mark it